# Getting ambiguous for the type in restassured while asserting statuscode

Tags: cucumber, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I was using cucumber BDD with restassured. My feature file contains * Then statuscode in 200 *
and in stepdefination while asserting the statuscode as paramter I was getting the above mentioned error.

I tried converting the feature file parameter to string literal and later asserting the expected status code, but getting different error.

Here is my code:

```java
@Then("statuscode is {int}") 
Public void status_code_is(Integer int) { 
    assertEqual(response.getStatusCode(),int) ; 
}
```

Comment: @Then("statuscode is {int}")
Public void status_code_is(Integer int)                                 {
assertEqual(response.getStatusCode(),int) ;
}

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please check the comment for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 problems here:

1. no `Public` in Java, it is `public`.
2. `int` is reservered keyword in Java, choose another name for parameter.

```java
public void status_code_is(Integer statusCode){
   assertEqual(response.getStatusCode(), statusCode) ; 
}
```

Comment: Changing Integer to int type, works for me.Thank you.